# Colocar WS no heroku

Tags: banco-de-dados, heroku, jersey

alguém ai sabe como devo configurar o persistence.xml para acessar uma base de dados do Heroku? Estou tentando com as credenciais que eles passam mas dá erro de senha para a aquele usuário.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

P.S: Meu app é um Ws feito com Jersey.

Abraço.

Comment: Edita a pergunta com o seu codigo, talvez esteja fazendo algo errado (so esconde as credenciais obviamente)

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde amigo, já consegui resolver o problema, eu inclui um "?sslmode=require" no final da url.

Grande abraço.